# adding padding to font awesome icon moves icon outside of parent

Tags: css

I want to make a number input and i have increase and decrease icons at the end of the parent side by side.

[image: like that]

The html code that makes this:

```
<div class="number_input_actions_container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-fw fa-minus number_input_btn number_input_btn_left"></i> 
    <i class="fa-solid fa-fw fa-plus number_input_btn number_input_btn_right"></i>
</div>
```

The css of the elements and some other that applies to them:

```
body {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fa-solid {
    display: flex !important;
}

.fa-fw {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.25em;
}

i::before {
    height: min-content;
    margin: auto;
}

.number_input_actions_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.number_input_btn {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  background-color: #efefef
}

.number_input_btn_right {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0px;
}
```

and whatever value of width i put to .number_input_btn the width stays like this:

[image]

[image]

Why is the plus and minus icons parent don't have width?.How can i fix this?.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I had to change this:

```
.fa-fw {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.25em;
}
```

to this:

```
.fa-fw {
  text-align: center;
  width: auto!important;
  min-width: 1.25em!important;
}
```

for some reason the  element had a weird min-width which was not set anywhere in the code.So reseting it worked.